# background wallpaper install location

Tags: wallpaper

I `yum install  desktop-backgrounds-waves` in Rocky 8.8 Linux.

When logged in (as root because i don't like sudo) I right click and choose `Change Background...` which opens up `Settings - Background` and there's the choice for `Background` and `Lock Screen`.

When I choose Background there, then there's 3 choices... `Wallpapers`, `Pictures`, `Colors`.

How does this work when choosing Wallpapers, how/where in Linux (Gnome) is it set to tell where to look for *Wallpapers* ?

dong `repoquery --installed -l desktop-backgrounds-waves` it responds with `/usr/share/backgrounds/waves/` for where all the `.png` files are.

What is the convention these days for installing & finding desktop background pictures/wallpapers in Linux?  Do I need to manually copy from `/usr/share/whatever` the pics to my `~/Pictures/` folder?  Because I do not know how else to do it, that seems to be the only way in the choose a background in that gnome background window.